# Navigate from one tab to a nested view of another tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to link from one tab to a nested view in another tab? I've tried two different methods and neither seem to work.

Here's my router config:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

In templates/tab-dash.html I have a link to a particular chat detail page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h1>My Chats</h1>
    <a href="#/tab/chats/1">Chat #1</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**From here I can navigate the chat detail page, however if I click the "Chats" tab button at the bottom nothing at all happens. I'd like it to bring me to the main Chats page.**

Another method I tried was using ui-sref instead of href:

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h1>My Chats</h1>
    <a ui-sref="tab.chat-detail{chatId:1}">Chat #1</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In this case I receive an error **Could not resolve 'tab.chat-detail{chatId:1}' from state 'tab.dash'**

What's the best way to link to a "detail" view from within another tab? My main is to make sure that clicking the tab button at the bottom always brings me to the parent page for that tab. Right now, in the first example, it gets stuck on the "detail" view.

Comment: Hmmm. I do this and there is no problem. Are you using ui-sref for all your navigation? It sounds like when you are going from tab-dash you are remaining in tab-dash despite moving to a child view of tab-chat.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Yes, I normally use ui-sref for all my navigation. However when I tried that here I get the error "Could not resolve...". That's why I tried the href approach as well, which works in that it allows me to get to the chat detail view, but doesn't work in that the tab button at the bottom is no longer functional.

Comment: Hmmm. I get what you're saying. The complication is my abstract state is one step up as I use a combined sidemenu and tabs view. I'd stick with using ui-sref as you'll generally get less problems with Ionic using that. This sounds like a question for the Ionic forums.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect I'll try posting on the Ionic forum as well. Thanks for giving it a look, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround. I am hiding the tab bar when navigating to nested view of another tab.
And showing it again when user navigates back to the root tab.

To know how to hide and show tab bar programmatically, check this link:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002644/4527624

Comment: Please don't post a  answer given link to another stackoverflow answer.If you think question is duplicate flagged them.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Shree. I am new to these rules. I will rectify next time. But the above answer is not duplicate, the solution is a combination of both the answers.